# Back/Forward buttons in Flex applications

Tags: apache-flex, flash, browser, usability

I have a Flex application which uses the BrowserManager class for enabling deep linking within the application. The URLs work fine through all browsers but the back/forward buttons work only with Firefox and Internet Explorer. Even that is a bit flaky and sometimes doesn't work. The buttons don't work in Chrome/Safari or any other browser.

Any ideas about how to make this work properly? If anyone has implemented something like this before in a Flex app then would like to hear about things to take care of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Flex: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-27034

It's fixed in Flex 4.5.